# write data to html with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read data from a serial port and display the value on HTML. I got data from my lpc1768, but when I click the button, nothing appears in textbox. Can I do this using only python?

Here's my code:

```
  import http.server,socketserver,logging,cgi,urllib,serial,time,sys
  hostName = "localhost"
  hostPort = 8080
  global c 
  c = 0
  form = cgi.FieldStorage()
  if len(sys.argv) > 2:
     PORT = int(sys.argv[2])
     I = sys.argv[1]
  elif len(sys.argv) > 1:
     PORT = int(sys.argv[1])
     I = ""
  else:
     PORT = 8080
     I = ""
  class ServerHandler((http.server).SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    ser = serial.Serial(
      port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
      baudrate=115200,
      parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
      stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
      bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
      )
    print ( ser.isOpen())
    while 1:
       c = ser.readline()
       print (ser.readline())

       break

    def do_GET(self):
      logging.warning("======= GET STARTED =======")
      logging.warning(self.headers)
      self.send_response(200)
      self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
      self.end_headers()
      self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title>", "utf-8"))
      self.wfile.write(bytes("</head>", "utf-8"))
      self.wfile.write(bytes("<body><p>This is a test.</p>", "utf-8"))
      self.wfile.write(bytes("<input type=text id=txt2>","utf-8"))
      self.wfile.write(bytes("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" onclick=document.getElementById(\"txt2\").value=c>","utf-8"))
      self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

  Handler = ServerHandler

  httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: You don't actually create a ServerHandler on the penultimate line, you just create an another name for the class. ServerHandler() would create one.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 my problem is I can't display value that I received in textbox

Comment: @Caleth sorry I'm not quite understand.I'm only a newbie this code I see from example in stackoverflow

Comment: Can you post what the python console prints

Comment: @Caleth
True b'1610612736\r\n'
rochacbruno Python http server version 0.1 (for testing purposes only)
Serving at: http://localhost:8080
WARNING:root:======= GET STARTED =======
WARNING:root:Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0 Iceweasel/31.7.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive


127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jun/2015 10:49:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: [edit] your question instead of putting additional info in comments.